# Which code is more efficient? (calling javascript function.)

Tags: javascript

common part:

```
var ext="txt", filename;
```

Which code would you prefer?

this one:

```
 function changeDocTitle() {
      document.title = filename + ext;
    }
 filename = "untitled";
 changeDocTitle();
```

Or this one:

```
function changeDocTitle(filename) {
  document.title = filename + ext;
}
changeDocTitle(filename = "untitled");
```

Also please tell the reason.
I know the do the same thing but any performance difference?

Comment: Passing a parameter is more efficient than relying on variables in a parent scope.

Comment: `(filename = "untitled")` - why?

Comment: there is a variable and its value should be changed as well.

Comment: Variable you can change it as when you are required

Comment: In both examples you are missing the ext variable. You are possibly relying on global variables which is a bad practice to get into.

Comment: the `ext` variable wont change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments in previous answer by @Mad Echet, you need a function that would change both filename and the doc title at the same time.

Speaking in terms of efficiency, the more the number of lines executed or functions called the longer the time taken.

But you do not have much of a choice here. Best you can do is wrap both up to one function:

```
function changeFilenameAndDocTitle(newFileName) {
  filename = newFileName; 
  document.title = newFileName + ext;
}
```

And call it as suggested with parameter.

```
changeFilenameAndDocTitle("untitled");
```

Strictly speaking with the modern browsers, this execution would happen in a flash, then again it depends on if this is all you want to do each time or more complex manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You probably come from a Python world where `function(variable=value)` has a meaning. In your second example you create a new variable called `filename` and assign it the value `"untitled"` and then pass this value on to the function. I doubt this is what you want to do, unless you need `filename` later on.

If you need `filename` do:

```
var filename = "untitled";
changeDocTitle(filename);
```

If you don't just do:

```
changeDocTitle("untitled");
```

Comment: there is a global variable called `filename`.

Comment: and whenever the filename changes, the function should be run. so I just want to know if I should run a single line that changes the `filename` and runs the function. instead of two line.

Comment: Ok, but you added this part afterwards. I cannot think of a case where it makes a big performance difference. If you already have a global variable, calling it without passing it to the function will save you some space but nothing that would make a difference. It is not very Javascripty to save space by resort to external variables, but this is not a general rule.